# How to add JQuery to html loaded from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have a div in a jsp like this :

```
<div id="response" class="response"></div>
```

This div, after making an ajax call to a servlet, is appended as :

```
<div id="response" class="response">
<h3>Connected as user : Tony</h3>
<p>You selected the procedure : <B>lg_resultsretrieval</B></p>
<div class="showbiz">
<label>Enter procedure input variables : </label></div> 
<div class="actual-input">
<label>Parameter1: </label><textarea name='text1' id='text1' class='txtarea' rows='1' cols='50'>starttime - timestamp without time zone</textarea><br> 
<label>Parameter2: </label><textarea name='text2' id='text2' class='txtarea' rows='1' cols='50'>endtime - timestamp without time zone</textarea><br> 
<label>Parameter3: </label><textarea name='text3' id='text3' class='txtarea' rows='1' cols='50'>in_sourceindicator - integer</textarea><br> 
<label>Parameter4: </label><textarea name='text4' id='text4' class='txtarea' rows='1' cols='50'>keyword - character varying</textarea><br> 
</div>
</div>
```

I wrote a jquery function for the textarea's as follows :

```
//submits only when the textbox value is valid
    $("#response").on("change", function() { 
              $("#Execute").click(function () {
                    if ($(".txtarea").val() == this.defaultValue)
                    {
                        alert("Please insert a valid value");
                        return false;
                    }
                });

              $("txtarea")
              .focus(function() {
                    if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
                        console.log('inside focus function');
                        this.value = '';
                    }
              })
              .blur(function() {
                    if (this.value === '') {
                        this.value = this.defaultValue;
                    }
            });       
            });
```

Problem is, the above code doesn't work although in the jquery documentation it says to use on function for dynamically loaded elements. How do I make it work ? Please suggest

Comment: 1) there is no element with id `Execute`
2) there is no element with tag `txtarea`

Comment: DIVS do not have change events.

Comment: @epascarello: The `change` event seems to propagate to `div` elements from child elements, though.  In this case the `textarea` elements.  Maybe that's browser-specific behavior?  Worth testing, I imagine.

Comment: @Justinas : txtarea is the class name of text area and Execute is the id of the button in the jsp code I've written.

Comment: @Karthik class selector is with dot `.txtarea`, and in your code you are showing, there is no buttons at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have div with id response. then after appending  html in this div you can bind all jquery event of added html like this:

```
 $("#response").on(EventName,htmlDom, function() { 
                 //to do your code
      });
```

e.g for textArea Try like this:

```
$("#response").on("focus","textarea", function() { 
         //to do your code
 });
```

Comment: Fastest answer .. Thanx

Comment: However, placeholder solved the problem. All that code was not needed at all. Thanx for the help anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If the `div` itself is being replaced in the DOM, then indeed any handler attached to that `div` will be lost.  Note how you attach the handler here:

```
$("#response").on("change", function() {
  // code
});
```

This attaches the handler directly to the `div` as it exists when the `$("#response")` selector is evaluated.  Handlers are attached to *elements*, not to dynamic selectors.  In order to retain the handler for elements which are added/replaced, you need to bind to a parent element and filter for the target element.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#response", function() {
  // code
});
```

This would bind the handler to the `document` object, which doesn't change so the handler won't be lost as child elements change.  (For reference, I actually [just blogged about this](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/on-on-or-event-delegation-explained.html) yesterday.)

Answer (score 2):

That will not work for dynamically added element.use:

```
$(document).on("change",'"#response"', function() { 
     //code here
 });
```